# "Too Many Initializer Values" in C++ function parameters

Tags: c++, function, parameters, pass-by-reference

This, "Too Many Initializer Values", error keeps occurring every time I try to pass by reference with these variables:

Main file. This is where the error occurs and where I'm having all of the trouble.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::string itemName;
    double itemPrice;
    double itemQuantity;
    double itemDiscount;

    //Opening input file
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("InputFile.txt");

    infile >> itemName;
    infile >> itemPrice;
    infile >> itemQuantity;
    infile >> itemDiscount;

    //Opening output file
    ifstream outfile;
    outfile.open("OutputFile.txt");

    //This is where the error occurs, a red underline at "itemQuantity"
    double calculateCost(itemPrice, itemQuantity, itemDiscount);
}
```

Function definition. Here you can see I'm trying to use "Pass By Reference".

```
#include <iostream>

double calculateCost(double &price, double &quantity, double &discountPct) {

    //Placeholder code
    std::cout << "Hello world.\n";
}
```

Header. I included the "&" symbols for the parameters here as well.

```
#pragma once

double calculateCost(double &price, double &quantity, double &discountPct);
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  Get rid of the return type in `double calculateCost(itemPrice, itemQuantity, itemDiscount);`.  i.e `calculateCost(itemPrice, itemQuantity, itemDiscount);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
double calculateCost(itemPrice, itemQuantity, itemDiscount);
```

is a declaration of a scalar object of the type double with the name of identifier calculateCost. Remove the type specifier

```
calculateCost(itemPrice, itemQuantity, itemDiscount);
```

Also take into account that the function shall have a return statement with an expression.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
double calculateCost(itemPrice, itemQuantity, itemDiscount);
```

the compiler thinks you are trying to declare a function local variable named `calculateCost`. Such a variable cannot be initialized by the contents within the parenthesis. To make the function call and capture the return value, use

```
double cost = calculateCost(itemPrice, itemQuantity, itemDiscount);
```